# Why does my code return </h2> when I set it to return as </input>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a todo site with edit mode and view mode. Full code is at https://repl.it/@UCYT5040/Notekeeper, but this is the JS I am having an issue with.

```js
let editMode = true;
let items = 1

function toggleEditMode() {
    console.log(editMode)
    if (editMode == true) {
        editMode = false;
        for (i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            document.getElementById('item' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = "<h1 id=\"itemTitle" + (i + 1) + "\">" + document.getElementById('itemTitle' + (i + 1)).value + "</h1>"
        }
    } else {
        editMode = true
        for (i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            document.getElementById('item' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"itemTitle" + (i + 1) + "\" value=\"" + document.getElementById('itemTitle' + (i + 1)).innerHTML + "></input>"
        }
    }
}
```

This ends up with

```
`<div id="item1">
    <input type="text" id="itemTitle1" value="New Note">
    </h1>
</div>`,
```

but it should be

```
`<div id="item1">
    <input type="text" id="itemTitle1" value="New Note"></input>. 
 </div>`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are void elements(`<input>`). This means they aren't designed to contain text or other elements, and as such do not need — and in fact, cannot have — a closing tag in HTML.

```
document.getElementById('item' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"itemTitle" + (i + 1) + "\" value=\"" + document.getElementById('itemTitle' + (i + 1)).innerHTML + "/>"
```